# javascript is not working with codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

i am just trying to learn some php framework.ans started with codeigniter.so you guys can understand that i am completely new with codeigniter.i am just tring to show a error message when my username and password field is empty.if not then submit the form.i wants both user and server side validation.problems is that js is not showing error message,also not submitting.
here my view code->

```
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>LOGIN</h2>
        <form method="post" name="loginForm">
            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tr>
                    <td>USERNAME</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="iusername" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>PASSWORD</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="ipassword" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input onclick="checkInputFields()" type="button" value="Login" name="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <br />

        <!-- Label to display error message -->
        <?php
        if(!empty($errorMessage)){?>
            <label name="errorMessage" id="ierrorMessage"><?php echo $errorMessage;?></label>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </center>
</body>
```

form is submiiting to the controller page,from where it is viewed.
my js code->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkInputFields(){
            if(document.getElementById('iusername').value == "" || document.getElementById('ipassword').value == ""){
                document.getElementById('ierrorMessage').innerHTML('You cant left username and password field empty.');
            }
            else{
                //document.forms[0].submit();
                document.loginForm.submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and my controller function->

```
    public function index(){
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $uName=$this->input->post('username');
        $uPass=$this->input->post('password');

        if($uName == "" || $uPass == ""){
            $message['errorMessage']='You cant left username and password field empty.';
            $this->load->view('login',$message);
        }else{
            if($this->varifyuser->checkuser($uName,$uPass)){

            $this->session->set_userdata('loggedin', true);

            redirect(base_url()."home", 'refresh');

            }else{
                $message['errorMessage']='Invalid username or password';
                $this->load->view('login',$message);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

controller function working absoletely fine.i checked,but  js is not working,WHY?.also i wants to check how to check validation both server and client end,in my code if js if off[if my will works] from will not submit.and php validation will not work.i also wants to know what is wrong with my coding architecture.experience brothes->please help me.

Comment: you can easily check this blank input with codeigniter validation,why you dont use that????

Answer (score 0):

The label

```
<label name="errorMessage" id="ierrorMessage"><?php echo $errorMessage;?></label>
```

Is not created if you have no errors on load page,then :

```
document.getElementById('ierrorMessage') /*is null*/
```

Comment: oh!imay be I CAN UNDESTAND.but why the form is not submitting.

Comment: try changing the attribute "name" of the input button. document.loginForm.submit() is not working with this input name.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery.Try like this..

```js
$("#login").on('click',function(){
username = $("#iusername").val();
password = $("#ipassword").val();
if(username=='' || password == ''){
console.log("You cant left username and password field empty.");
alert("You cant left username and password field empty.");
}

else{
$("#loginForm").submit();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
        <h2>LOGIN</h2>
        <form method="post" name="loginForm">
            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tr>
                    <td>USERNAME</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="iusername" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>PASSWORD</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="ipassword" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" id="login" name="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <br />
        </center>
```